# Inicializar Array que es propiedad privada de una clase en otra!

Tags: java, array, herencia

Tengo un proyecto para un ejercicio estructurado en tres packages:

- Aplicación (Main)

  ```
  package aplicacion;

  import mountainbike.MountainBike;

  public class ProbandoMountainBike {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  MountainBike mb = new MountainBike();

  mb.setTamanoRueda(1);
  mb.setNumPlatos(1);
  mb.setNumPinones(11);

  mb.setNumDientes() //**************************



  double diametro = 0;   // Declaro esta variable para sacar el valor en pulgados según tamaño de rueda

  if (mb.getTamanoRueda() == 1) {  // Damos valor al diametro según el tamaño rueda

      diametro = 26;

  } else if (mb.getTamanoRueda() == 2) {

      diametro = 27.5;

  } else if (mb.getTamanoRueda() == 3) {

      diametro = 29;
  }

  System.out.println("Objeto utilizando el constructor parametrizado");

  System.out.println("\nDiámetro de la rueda: " + diametro);

  }

  }
  ```
- Bicicleta (padre)

  ```
  package bicicleta;

  public class Bicicleta {

  private int tamanoRueda ;   // 1 - 2 - 3 para tamaños 26 - 27.5 - 29
  private double velocidad;   // Velocidad Bicicleta
  private int numPlatos;      // Platos que tiene la bicicleta
  private int numPinones;     // Piñones que tiene la bicicleta

  public Bicicleta() {

  }

  public Bicicleta(int tamanoRueda, double velocidad, int numPlatos, int numPinones) {
      this.tamanoRueda = tamanoRueda;
      this.velocidad = velocidad;
      this.numPlatos = numPlatos;
      this.numPinones = numPinones;
  }

  public int getTamanoRueda() {

      return tamanoRueda;
  }

  public void setTamanoRueda(int tamanoRueda) {
      this.tamanoRueda = tamanoRueda;
  }

  public double getVelocidad() {
      return velocidad;
  }

  public void setVelocidad(double velocidad) {
      this.velocidad = velocidad;
  }

  public int getNumPlatos() {
      return numPlatos;
  }

  public void setNumPlatos(int numPlatos) {
      this.numPlatos = numPlatos;
  }

  public int getNumPinones() {
      return numPinones;
  }

  public void setNumPinones(int numPinones) {
      this.numPinones = numPinones;
  }

  public void acelera(double aceleracion) {
      this.velocidad += aceleracion;
  }

  public void frena(double desaceleracion) {
      this.velocidad -= desaceleracion;
  }
  ```

  }
- Mountain Bike (subclase hereda propiedades de Bicicleta)

  ```
  package mountainbike;

  import bicicleta.Bicicleta;
  import java.lang.reflect.Array;


  public class MountainBike extends Bicicleta {

  private int [] numDientes = new int [15];
  private int plato;
  private int pinon;

  public MountainBike() {

  }


  public MountainBike(int[] numDientes, int plato, int pinon, int tamanoRueda, double velocidad, int numPlatos, int numPinones) {
      super(tamanoRueda, velocidad, numPlatos, numPinones);
      this.plato = plato;
      this.pinon = pinon;
  }



  public int[] getNumDientes() {
      return numDientes;
  }

  public void setNumDientes(int[] numDientes) {
      this.numDientes = numDientes;
  }

  public int getPlato() {
      return plato;
  }

  public void setPlato(int plato) {
      this.plato = plato;
  }

  public int getPinon() {
      return pinon;
  }

  public void setPinon(int pinon) {
      this.pinon = pinon;
  }

  public double cmAvanza(){

      double cm = 0;


      cm = (numDientes[plato-1] / numDientes[pinon+2])* 2 * Math.PI * ((getTamanoRueda()*2.54)/2);;        

      return cm;
  }
  ```

  }

El problema es que una de las propiedades de Mountain Bike es un Array [15] privado el cual nose inicializar en el Main. Ya que en el enenunciado del problema se me dice:

> Programar una clase de nombre MountainBike, que herede de Bicicleta, y
>   que además añada las siguientes propiedades y métodos: Propiedades
>   (privadas):
>   - numDientes: array de 15 enteros que almacenará en sus tres primeras posiciones el número de dientes de cada uno de los tres posibles
>   platos que puede tener una MountainBike. En el caso de tener menos de
>   tres platos solo tendrán valores las posiciones necesarias del array.
>   En las restantes posiciones se almacenarán el número de dientes de los
>   piñones que tenga la bicicleta

Por lo que el array lo debo declarar como privado en `MoutainBike` y después en el último punto se me pide:

> Hacer un programa en el que se declare un objeto de la clase
>   `MountainBike`. Crear el objeto utilizando el constructor por defecto.
>   Asignarle al objeto los valores: tamanoRueda: 1 numPlatos: 1
>   numPinones:11 numDientes: 22-xx-xx-11-13-15-17-19-21-24-28-32-36-42-xx
>   (xx podría tener cualquier valor, ya que en este objeto no se
>   utilizan) plato: 1 pinon: 5
>
> Visualizar los datos de esta bicicleta, y los centímetros que avanza
>   en cada  pedalada.
>
> Crear otro objeto pasándole sus valores iniciales mediante el
>   constructor. Los valores serán: tamanoRueda: 3 numPlatos: 2
>   numPinones:11 numDientes: 22-36-xx-11-13-15-17-19-21-24-28-32-36-42-xx
>   (xx podría tener cualquier valor, ya que en este objeto no se
>   utilizan) plato: 2 pinon: 1

Comment: Hola,

Has inicializado un array en las instancias de MountainBaik (numDientes), es decir le has dicho a java que almacene un espacio en disco para 15 posiciones de int. Todas las instancias de MountanBiek tendrán ese espacio reservado. Ahora bien, tampoco podemos ver la implementación de Bicicleta ni a qué array te refieres con ese de 13 posiciones. ¿Podrías darnos más datos?

Comment: El array de 13 estaba mal son 15. Declare el array de 15 posiciones que son las que necesito sacar cuando:

- Utilizando constructor por defecto debe ser: 22-0-0-11-13-15-17-19-21-24-28-32-36-42-0

- Pasándole valores iniciales mediante constructor: 22-36-0-11-13-15-17-19-21-24-28-32-36-42-0

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que entiendo, desde el main deseas asignarle los 15 valores a numDientes, entonces podrias cambiar el constructor para recibir como parametro un array asi:

```
public MountainBike(int plato, int pinon, int tamanoRueda, double velocidad, int numPlatos, int numPinones,int[] numDientes) {

    super(tamanoRueda, velocidad, numPlatos, numPinones);
    this.plato = plato;
    this.pinon = pinon;
    this.numDientes = numDientes;
}
```

y desde el main simplemente creas un array con los valores que deseas y los pasas como parametro, algo así:

```
int[] dientes = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
MountainBike mb = new MountainBike(plato,pinon,tamanoRueda,velocidad,numPlatos,numPinones,dientes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo que buscaba era lo siguiente declaro el constructor de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MountainBike extends Bicicleta {

    private int [] numDientes = new int [15];
    private int plato;
    private int pinon;

    public MountainBike() {

    }


    public MountainBike(int[] numDientes, int plato, int pinon, int tamanoRueda, double velocidad, int numPlatos, int numPinones) {
        super(tamanoRueda, velocidad, numPlatos, numPinones);
        this.numDientes = numDientes;
        this.plato = plato;
        this.pinon = pinon;
    }
```

Y para inicializar el array desde main tenía que usar la siguiente expresión:

```
public class ProbandoMountainBike {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MountainBike mb = new MountainBike();

        mb.setTamanoRueda(1);
        mb.setNumPlatos(1);
        mb.setNumPinones(11);
        mb.setNumDientes(new int[]{22, 0, 0, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 24, 28, 32, 36, 42, 0});
        mb.setPlato(1);
        mb.setPinon(5);
```

No me enteraba por que tenía que usar el "***new int[]{xxx}***" . Ahora lo que necesito es imprimir por pantala por ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("Número de dientes de los 11 piñones: " + b.getNumDientes());
```

Viene siendo de la posicion [3] a la [14]?????